# Could someone explain this code for me?

Tags: python, generator

Can someone explain this piece of code for me, in simple terms.

```
prompts = ("Enter Strength Attribute, between 1 and 50: ", "Enter Skill Attribute, between 1 and 50: ") # I already now this so no need to explain it 

answers = [int(input(p)) for p in prompts]
if not all(0 < a <=50 for a in answers):
    # other code here
```

Is it a generator?

And how does it work?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: It's one list comprehension and one generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a list comprehension and a generator expression.

The list comprehension is:

```
[int(input(p)) for p in prompts]
```

and produces a list of integers from a list of prompts, asking the user for a series of numeric values.

It could also be expressed as:

```
answers = []
for p in prompts:
    result = int(input(p))
    answers.append(result)
```

Next is:

```
(0 < a <=50 for a in answers)
```

which is the generator expression. It tests if each of the numbers is a value between 0 (exclusive) and 50 (inclusive).

The [`all()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) will loop over the generator expression one result at a time, and will return `False` the moment one of those results is `False`, or `True` when it exhausts the generator results and no `False` values were found.

You could replace the `if all(...)` test with:

```
result = True
for a in answers:
    if not 0 < a <= 50:
        result = False
        break

if result:
```

This would achieve the same effect; loop over `answers` one by one, but stop looping early if any of the tests was `False` (not a number greater than 0 and smaller than or equal to 50).

Answer (score 1):

```
answers = [int(input(p)) for p in prompts]
```

This is a list comprehension. It could be written as a `for` loop like this:

```
answers = []
for p in prompts:
    resp = int(input(p))
    answers.append(resp)
```

---

```
if not all(0 < a <=50 for a in answers):
```

This is a generator, wrapped in `all` (a built in function that returns whether all elements are true) You could write that as a function:

```
def all(answers):
    for a in answer:
        if not 0 < a <= 50:
            return False  # note this short-circuits, stopping the loop
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a list comprehension.

The first line does exactly the same as:

```
answers=[]
for p in prompts:
   a=int(input(p))
   answers.append(a)
```

The part of the second line behind the if condition does exactly the same as:

```
for a in answers:
        if a <= 0 or a > 50:
                 return False
return True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for p in prompts
```

enumerates the prompts

```
int(input(p))
```

asks the user for an input, using the `p` as a prompt, then try to coerce the input as an int

```
answers = [...]
```

makes answers a list of all the inputs converted in ints (this is a comprehension list)

```
(0 < a <=50 for a in answers)
```

This is a generator. It creates an iterable containing the test `0 < a <=50` for each value in the answers list

```
if not all(...)
```

Tests all elements in the generator. if any one is false, do `other code`